Bootstrap Carousel (5.3) not working on Rails 7
I can't find the issue and I've tried a million times. Why isn't this code working? It's the same as in the Bootstrap website minimally modified.
It just shows one picture, but the buttons are not working at all.
<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <%= image_tag("novia-1.jpg", class:"d-block w-100", alt: "Slide 1") %>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <%= image_tag("novia-2.jpg", class:"d-block w-100", alt: "Slide 2") %>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <%= image_tag("novia-3.jpg", class:"d-block w-100", alt: "Slide 3") %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>


Are you sure bootstrap js is being loaded?

How did you install bootstrap? Try using https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails.

Add
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

To application.html to test that your bootstrap works.
After this u can remove that and install bootstrap properly

Oh thank you so much Genry, that actually made it work! Still a rookie as you can see :-)
